# Intersecting time periods in two Spark dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a query to do, which overchallenges me intellectually.

I have two Spark dataframes. In `df1` I have the following structure

| groupIdx | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 101 | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 | 2023-01-01 13:00:00 |
| 102 | 2023-01-01 13:00:00 | 2023-01-01 13:15:00 |
| 103 | 2023-01-01 13:15:00 | 2023-01-03 11:00:00 |

etc.

In `df2` I have this exemplary structure:

| categ | start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 10:00:00 | 2023-01-01 10:50:00 | 1.092 |
| A | 2023-01-01 10:50:00 | 2023-01-01 18:02:00 | 3.2 |
| A | 2023-01-01 18:02:00 | 2023-01-02 07:15:00 | 0.1 |
| A | 2023-01-02 07:15:00 | 2023-01-05 04:07:00 | 0.3 |
| B | 2023-01-01 07:42:00 | 2023-01-01 08:50:00 | 5.5 |
| B | 2023-01-01 08:50:00 | 2023-01-01 13:02:00 | 4.1 |
| B | 2023-01-01 13:02:00 | 2023-01-04 12:10:00 | 0.7 |

etc.

The objective is now to use the periods encoded within `df1` (i.e. the `start` and `end` times), and compute the average of `value` for each category (A, B, ...) in `df2` using the periods in this dataframe as weights. It means, for every category in `df2` I want to have a copy of `df1` with an additional column `average` which contains the weighted average of `value` for this category as encoded in `df2`. And this weight depends on the overlap of the two periods. So for example, for the group with index 101 (00:00 - 12:00 on first of January) and category A, the value 1.092 should receive a weight of 50min/(12*60min), the numerator here is 10:50-10:00 and the denominator is 12:00-00:00. Ignore that the periods in `df2` do not completely overlap those in `df1`, it's just a matter of my example, meaning, you can assume that they will overlap.

I implemented this in pandas via a loop over the rows of `df2` and `df1`:

```
for categ in categories:
    pdf2 = spark_df2.where(f"categ=='{categ}'").toPandas() # take subset of df2 data for this category
    pdf2.sort_values("start")
    pdf_out = pdf1.copy()
    raw = {}
    for idx, row_df1 in pdf1.iterrows():
        r_df1   = (row_df1["end"]-row_df1["start"]).total_seconds() # duration of df1 period
        dfx     = pdf2[(pdf2["start"]<=row_df1["end"]) & (pdf2["end"]>row_df1["start"])] # subset of df2 data overlapping with that period in df1
        vals    = []
        weights = []
        for jdx, row_df2 in dfx.iterrows():
            start = row_df2["start"] if row_df2["start"]>=row_df1["start"] else row_df1["start"] # truncate df2 period at starting point of df1 if df2 start is earlier
            end   = row_df2["end"  ] if row_df2["end"  ]<=row_df1["end"  ] else row_df1["end"  ] # truncate df2 period at end point of df1 if df2 end is later
            r_df2 = (end-start).total_seconds() # duration of df2 data
            vals   .append(row_df2["avlue"])
            weights.append(r_df2/r_df1     )
        raw[row_df2["groupIdx"]] = 0 if len(vals)==0 else np.average(vals, weights=weights)
    pdf_out["average"] = imonGroups["groupIdx"].map(raw)
    print(pdf_out)
    break ## only first category for now
```

As you can see, I make a copy of `df1` for every category in `df2` and add a new column `average` to contain the average of values of that category for each period.
I bet there are better ways to implement this even in pandas. But the point is that it is super slow already for one category, cause I have on the scale of billions of entries in `df2` for a total of more than 4300 categories.

My question: is there a much more efficient way to implement this, preferably using a complex SQL statement to exploit the computational advantages of it and to circumvent the nested loops?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Kind regards,
conni

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to do in SQL. https://bpa.st/DABAO

Comment: Hmm thanks. I'm not expert enough to complete it: how do you ensure this is done separately for every group and category?

Comment: Ah you probably can just combine the two DFs in the necessary way as you did and then do that query to build the weights and compute the average. Lemme try that..

Comment: So, what is your expected data?

Answer (score 0):

For reference: jqurious basically solved it. Do a join of the two dataframes and then run the command he posted. I'll add it here for book-keeping:

```
duckdb.sql("""
from df1, df2
select 
   *,
   abs(epoch(least(df1.end, df2.end) - greatest(df1.start, df2.start))::float) as seconds2,
   epoch(df1.end - df1.start)::float as seconds1,
   seconds2 / seconds1 as weight
""")
```

Then later one can build the average value for each index via a `groupby` statement.

Thank you again!